# how do i get results that are currently in alert pop-up, to be entered in an input in html

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I get results that are currently in an alert pop-up, to be entered in an `<input>` in HTML?

Here is my current code:

```
const Callprice = parseInt(S.value) + parseInt(SP.value);

alert(Callprice);
```

How can I have `Callprice` entered in an HTML input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="callpriceinput">
```

JS

```
const Callprice = parseInt(S.value) + parseInt(SP.value);

alert(Callprice);

var input = document.getElementById("callpriceinput");
input.value = Callprice;
```

This should work.

Comment: how would you get the input.value to stick?

Comment: @CurtisOverbey set the `disabled` property on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
document.getElementById("/*Here's your input id*/").value = Callprice;
```